# How to process a string with preg_replace and preg_quote (case insensitive)?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text:

> Curabitur nec bibendum erat. Sed a scelerisque arcu, facilisis
>   bibendum mauris. Mauris sed sapien volutpat, volutpat risus in,
>   bibendum odio. Vestibulum eget neque a lorem CURABITUR rhoncus.
>   Aenean mollis ipsum ut facilisis egestas. Pellentesque finibus sed
>   ante eget interdum. Nunc fringilla ante a egestas mattis. Sed
>   tincidunt libero a dapibus bibendum. Morbi ac sapien vehicula,
>   condimentum justo eget, curabitur nisl. Cras rutrum molestie diam, ac
>   maximus mauris auctor quis. Ut vel diam nunc. Aliquam auctor, magna ac
>   finibus fermentum, orci libero consectetur magna, id scelerisque
>   tellus sem et orci.

In PHP I would like to wrap the word "curabitur" with the tag `<mark>` like `<mark>$1</mark>` using insensitive casing.

This following code works :

```
return preg_replace("/(" . $needle . ")/mi", "<mark>$1</mark>", $haystack );
```

Output :

> **<mark>Curabitur</mark>** nec bibendum erat. Sed a scelerisque arcu, facilisis
>   bibendum mauris. Mauris sed sapien volutpat, volutpat risus in,
>   bibendum odio. Vestibulum eget neque a lorem **<mark>CURABITUR</mark>** rhoncus. Aenean
>   mollis ipsum ut facilisis egestas. Pellentesque finibus sed ante eget
>   interdum. Nunc fringilla ante a egestas mattis. Sed tincidunt libero a
>   dapibus bibendum. Morbi ac sapien vehicula, condimentum justo eget,
>   **<mark>curabitur</mark>** nisl. Cras rutrum molestie diam, ac maximus mauris auctor
>   quis. Ut vel diam nunc. Aliquam auctor, magna ac finibus fermentum,
>   orci libero consectetur magna, id scelerisque tellus sem et orci.

BUT if you have this text :

> [Curabitur] nec bibendum erat. Sed a scelerisque arcu, facilisis
>   bibendum mauris. Mauris sed sapien volutpat, volutpat risus in,
>   bibendum odio. Vestibulum eget neque a lorem [CURABITUR] rhoncus. Aenean
>   mollis ipsum ut facilisis egestas. Pellentesque finibus sed ante eget
>   interdum. Nunc fringilla ante a egestas mattis. Sed tincidunt libero a
>   dapibus bibendum. Morbi ac sapien vehicula, condimentum justo eget,
>   [curabitur] nisl. Cras rutrum molestie diam, ac maximus mauris auctor
>   quis. Ut vel diam nunc. Aliquam auctor, magna ac finibus fermentum,
>   orci libero consectetur magna, id scelerisque tellus sem et orci.

and `$needle = [curabitur]` you should use `preg_quote()` to escape characters `[`,`]`

However the following does **NOT** work:

```
return preg_replace("/(" . preg_quote( $needle ) . ")/mi", "<mark>$1</mark>", $haystack );
```

because `$1` was modified by `preg_quote()`.

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by *`$1` was modified by `preg_quote()`*? It is modified so that the regex engine could parse it as a literal text. You do not have any issue to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested it without preg_quote but using your desired needle and it works like a charm:

```
$haystack = "[Curabitur] nec bibendum erat. Sed a scelerisque arcu, facilisis bibendum mauris. Mauris sed sapien volutpat, volutpat risus in, bibendum odio. Vestibulum eget neque a lorem CURABITUR rhoncus. Aenean mollis ipsum ut facilisis egestas. Pellentesque finibus sed ante eget interdum. Nunc fringilla ante a egestas mattis. Sed tincidunt libero a dapibus bibendum. Morbi ac sapien vehicula, condimentum justo eget, curabitur nisl. Cras rutrum molestie diam, ac maximus mauris auctor quis. Ut vel diam nunc. Aliquam auctor, magna ac finibus fermentum, orci libero consectetur magna, id scelerisque tellus sem et orci.";
$needle = "curabitur";

echo preg_replace("/(\[" . $needle . "\])/mi", "<mark>$1</mark>", $haystack );
```

The result is:

> `<mark>[Curabitur]</mark>` nec bibendum erat. Sed a scelerisque arcu,
>   facilisis bibendum mauris. Mauris sed sapien volutpat, volutpat risus
>   in, bibendum odio. Vestibulum eget neque a lorem CURABITUR rhoncus.
>   Aenean mollis ipsum ut facilisis egestas. Pellentesque finibus sed
>   ante eget interdum. Nunc fringilla ante a egestas mattis. Sed
>   tincidunt libero a dapibus bibendum. Morbi ac sapien vehicula,
>   condimentum justo eget, curabitur nisl. Cras rutrum molestie diam, ac
>   maximus mauris auctor quis. Ut vel diam nunc. Aliquam auctor, magna ac
>   finibus fermentum, orci libero consectetur magna, id scelerisque
>   tellus sem et orci.

I simply escaped the brackets with a backslash `\[` (see the example, this is what basically `preg_quote()` should do.

Then I tried with:

```
$needle = preg_quote("[curabitur]");
echo preg_replace("/(" . $needle . ")/mi", "<mark>$1</mark>", $haystack );
```

QED. It works like a charm. Your problem does not exist, the code works.

Comment: Yes, it works. the problem was during a previous treatment. I´m sorry.